# Unable to get an element from a php array when using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

My goal here is to get the string out of the array that has been returned by PHP when using a MySQL database Select Statement. I know that the array is working fine because when I print_r I get

```
        stdClass Object ( [data] => 1 [name] => [array] => 6; )
```

But when I try to get the array part with echo $row[0]['array']; the php interpreter fails at that line. How do I access the string [array] => 6; using the array notation?

Here is my attempt:

```
        $row = $result->fetch_object();
        //print_r($row);     
        echo $row[0]['array'];
        echo "<br/>";
```

Comment: Try echo $row->array;

Comment: You fetch an object, not an array, so you have to fetch the value using `$row->'array'`.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks guys I am new to PHP

Comment: Definitely, I would have done so right away but there is a 10 minute delay or something before you can accept an answer. Thanks though !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $row = $result->fetch_object();  
    echo $row->array;
    echo "<br/>";
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will never be just code and will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.